# Uploading a profile picture via PHP API

Tags: php, image, profile, desire2learn, valence

I am having trouble uploading a profile picture for a user. I keep getting a 404 error, which the API docs tells me indicates the profile can't be found. However, above the code I'll display in a sec, I have code to retrieve the profile, and it does exist for the particular userId I'm using. Additionally:

- This is with the PHP SDK
- The account I used to authenticate with does have access to edit user profiles
- The test image I'm using does exist and I am able to read it

Here's my code. It's a little sloppy, but I'll clean it up once I get this going for this particular test user:

```
$file = "testimage.jpeg";
$image_data = file_get_contents($file);

// Build our data
$uid = uniqid();
$data = "--" . $uid . "\r\n".
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profileImage\"; filename=\"profileImage.jpeg\"\r\n".
    "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n".
    "\r\n".
    $image_data . "\r\n".
    "--" . $uid . "--";

$success = false;
$tryAgain = true;
$numAttempts = 1;
$url = "/d2l/api/lp/1.0/profile/user/".$userId."/image";
$uri = $opContext->createAuthenticatedUri($url, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
while ($tryAgain && $numAttempts < MAX_NUM_ATTEMPTS) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Disposition: multipart/form-data; boundary='.$uid,
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode  = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $contentType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
    $responseCode = $opContext->handleResult($response, $httpCode, $contentType);
    if ($responseCode == D2LUserContext::RESULT_OKAY) {
        $success = true;
        $tryAgain = false;
    }
    elseif ($responseCode == D2LUserContext::RESULT_INVALID_TIMESTAMP) {
        // Try again since time skew should now be fixed.
        $tryAgain = true;
    }
    else {      // Something bad happened
        echo "here:\r\n".
            $httpCode.
            "\r\n\r\n".
            $responseCode;
        exit;
    }
    $numAttempts++;
}
```

I'm at a loss as to what I'm missing. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Edit: I just noticed this section in the API docs:

> Note
>
> In order to use this action, the service must have granted the application specific permission to do so (that is, granted permission to the specific application ID and key to attempt this action).

I'll inquire if our app ID/Key does indeed have permission. I thought it did, but maybe I was given incorrect information. I'll inquire about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that I use that works. I use the PHP Api to get an user context object and do the rest through curl.

$opContext - from the PHP API

$user_id - from d2l

$filename - image filename on server

$filepath - path to file on server (I have faculty and students in different places)

$filetype - for the mimetype

```
static function set_user_image($opContext,$user_id,$filename,$filepath,$filetype){
    $fp = fopen($filepath.$filename, 'r');
    $contents = fread($fp, filesize($filepath.$filename));
    fclose($fp);
    $random_hash = "xxBOUNDARYxx";
    $request ="--".$random_hash."\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n{\"Text\":\"Some comment\", \"HTML\":null}\r\n\r\n--".
                   $random_hash."\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profileimage\"; filename="."\"$filename\""."\r\nContent-Type: image/$filetype\r\n\r\n".
                   $contents."\r\n\r\n--".$random_hash;

    $length=strlen($request);
    $url = $opContext->createAuthenticatedUri("/d2l/api/lp/1.1/profile/user/$user_id/image","POST");

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("HTTP/1.1", "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=xxBOUNDARYxx","Content-Length:".$length));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);             
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked for me. I'm still going through it to compare and try and see exactly what is wrong with my code (just for my own understanding for future work with this), but yeah, this worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it worked for you. I found writing my own wrapper library for the D2L API has helped in so many cases.

Comment: Agreed -- in order to do my own internal work and testing, one of the first things I did was write a (fairly crude) set of wrappers around the D2L Python SDK, and it helped a great deal, especially with finicky operations like binary data uploads.